# LINQ conditional join

Tags: linq-to-entities

Is there any way I can rewrite this piece of code so that I don't have to duplicate the `join` and `where` clauses in multiple queries?

```
if (categoryId > 0)
{
    query = from p in _productRepository.Table
            from pv in p.ProductVariants.DefaultIfEmpty()
            from pc in p.ProductCategories.Where(pc => pc.CategoryId == categoryId)
            join psa in _productSpecificationAttributeRepository.Table on p.Id equals psa.ProductId
            join sao in _specificationAttributeOptionRepository.Table on psa.SpecificationAttributeOptionId equals sao.Id
            join sa in _specificationAttributeRepository.Table on sao.SpecificationAttributeId equals sa.Id
            where p.Published && pv.Published && !p.Deleted && psa.AllowFiltering &&
            (!pv.AvailableStartDateTimeUtc.HasValue || pv.AvailableStartDateTimeUtc.Value < nowUtc) &&
            (!pv.AvailableEndDateTimeUtc.HasValue || pv.AvailableEndDateTimeUtc.Value > nowUtc)
            select new {sa, sao};
}
else if (brandId > 0)
{
    query = from p in _productRepository.Table
            from pv in p.ProductVariants.DefaultIfEmpty()
            from pb in p.ProductBrands.Where(pb => pb.BrandId == brandId)
            join psa in _productSpecificationAttributeRepository.Table on p.Id equals psa.ProductId
            join sao in _specificationAttributeOptionRepository.Table on psa.SpecificationAttributeOptionId equals sao.Id
            join sa in _specificationAttributeRepository.Table on sao.SpecificationAttributeId equals sa.Id
            where p.Published && pv.Published && !p.Deleted && psa.AllowFiltering &&
            (!pv.AvailableStartDateTimeUtc.HasValue || pv.AvailableStartDateTimeUtc.Value < nowUtc) &&
            (!pv.AvailableEndDateTimeUtc.HasValue || pv.AvailableEndDateTimeUtc.Value > nowUtc)
            select new {sa, sao};
}

//only distinct attributes (group by ID)
query = from x in query
        group x by x.sao.Id into xGroup
        orderby xGroup.Key
        select xGroup.FirstOrDefault();
```

The only thing that changes between the 2 queries is this join:

```
from pc in p.ProductCategories.Where(pc => pc.CategoryId == categoryId)
```

with this join:

```
from pb in p.ProductBrands.Where(pb => pb.BrandId == brandId)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a good night's sleep i came up with the solution, which is very simple - split the query in 2 parts:

```
if (categoryId > 0)
{
    q1 = from p in _productRepository.Table
         from pc in p.ProductCategories.Where(pc => pc.CategoryId == categoryId)
         select p;
}
else if (brandId > 0)
{
    q1 = from p in _productRepository.Table
         from pb in p.ProductBrands.Where(pb => pb.BrandId == brandId)
         select p;
}
var query = from p in q1
            from pv in p.ProductVariants.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join psa in _productSpecificationAttributeRepository.Table on p.Id equals psa.ProductId
            join sao in _specificationAttributeOptionRepository.Table on psa.SpecificationAttributeOptionId equals sao.Id
            join sa in _specificationAttributeRepository.Table on sao.SpecificationAttributeId equals sa.Id
            where p.Published && pv.Published && !p.Deleted && psa.AllowFiltering &&
            (!pv.AvailableStartDateTimeUtc.HasValue || pv.AvailableStartDateTimeUtc.Value < nowUtc) &&
            (!pv.AvailableEndDateTimeUtc.HasValue || pv.AvailableEndDateTimeUtc.Value > nowUtc)
            select new { sa, sao };

//only distinct attributes (group by ID)
query = from x in query
        group x by x.sao.Id into xGroup
        orderby xGroup.Key
        select xGroup.FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you moved the join into a where clause, since it doesn't appear to be using either the categories of brands for anything else.  Would this work?

```
query = from p in _productRepository.Table
        from pv in p.ProductVariants.DefaultIfEmpty()
        join psa in _productSpecificationAttributeRepository.Table on p.Id equals psa.ProductId
        join sao in _specificationAttributeOptionRepository.Table on psa.SpecificationAttributeOptionId equals sao.Id
        join sa in _specificationAttributeRepository.Table on sao.SpecificationAttributeId equals sa.Id
        where
        ((categoryId > 0 && p.ProductCategories.Any(pc => pc.CategoryId == categoryId)) ||
        (brandId > 0 && p.ProductBrands.Any(pb => pb.BrandId == brandId))) &&
        p.Published && pv.Published && !p.Deleted && psa.AllowFiltering &&
        (!pv.AvailableStartDateTimeUtc.HasValue || pv.AvailableStartDateTimeUtc.Value < nowUtc) &&
        (!pv.AvailableEndDateTimeUtc.HasValue || pv.AvailableEndDateTimeUtc.Value > nowUtc)
        select new { sa, sao };
```

Comment: I don't think this is going to work because the line `from pc in p.ProductCategories.Where(pc => pc.CategoryId == categoryId)` produces a CROSS JOIN in SQL, whereas the where clause in your answer does not.